# Making a Pull Request to remote upstream after deleting local .git folder

Tags: git, github, .git-folder

I recently deleted my local .git folder. When trying to make a new PR to my remote/upstream, I can't because I've deleted my own local git history and I'm getting this message when trying to Compare and Open a PR:

`There isn’t anything to compare.
X:master and myRepo:x_branch are entirely different commit histories.`

How can I merge the upstream's commit history to mine, then submit the new code that's in the PR?

I am thinking of rebasing, but I'm not certain if that would do it.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to

1. Re-clone the repository into a new folder
2. Checkout the same point in time that you started making changes
3. Merge your files into the new cloned repository
4. Verify your changes with `git status` and `git diff`

This will allow you to remake your changes at the proper point in time and then you can push your changes to the server and submit a PR